# Is it good choice to use Adobe Air (html & Javascript) to develop Point of Sale desktop application?

Tags: javascript, air, adobe

Question: Is Adobe Air (HTML & JavaScript) a good technology choice for developing a restaurant PoS system?:

We tried out Adobe Air (HTML & JavaScript) and SQLite for desktop application to implement billing module for Restaurant Point of Sale system.

Billing module primarily does following things.

- Generate bills with having heavy usage.
- Have an interface with Printer, Barcode reader, Cash Drawers and other desktop peripherals for PoS system functionality.
- Have an offline support. Whenever system being online, application will sync data with web server.

Evaluating with thermal printer, we found difficulties of Air framework (html + javascript) to get quality print. With intense search, We did work around by zooming out and fix the area size with the data needed.

So is it a good choice to continue with Adobe Air as technology platform to develop restaurant PoS system considering upcoming future challenges?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: What do you mean by (html & javascript)?  With AIR, you code one app (one source code) and deploy to native IOS apps, native Android apps, desktop .exe, and desktop browser .swf.  You can export to canvas by converting code to createjs too.  AIR does perfect vector printouts.